# How to convert python code in a text file to python code inside a program

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a text file with the text below:
`{'Maps': {'Usefulness':80,'Accesibility':70,'Popularity':90}`
(the dictionary carries on that's why there may be a few syntax issues)
How do I convert this text into python code inside my program?
eg:
if the text files name is x.txt

```
textfile = convert(x.txt)
print(list(textfile.keys()))
```

the output would look something like

```
['Maps','Drive','Chrome']
```

Comment: Pretty sure you meant `convert('x.txt')`, not `convert(x.txt)`.  And `keys` already returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the json module

```
import json

with open('x.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print(data.keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate a string (like the one you get from reading a text file) as Python code:

```
import ast
s = """{
    'Maps': {
        'Usefulness':80,
        'Accesibility':70,
        'Popularity':90
        }
    }"""
ast.literal_eval(s)
# output: {'Maps': {'Usefulness': 80, 'Accesibility': 70, 'Popularity': 90}}
```

Reading from a text file:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    result = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
print(list(result.keys()))
```

If your text file is just a dictionary you can also use the `json` module. But the more generalist answer is to use `ast.literal_eval`.